# Convert vue3+vite project to SSR

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite, server-side-rendering

I have a project built with vue js 3 + vite
How can i make it ssr
In the simplest way possible, since I don't have much time
To become better for SEO

I tried more than one educational content, but the methods were difficult or incomprehensible. Can someone help me with this topic?

Comment: this code template should give you an idea about Vue + SSR with vite https://github.com/bluwy/create-vite-extra/tree/master/template-ssr-vue

Comment: @MrXQ 
thank you so much
I started to understand how things worked
But I have a question now, if I want to say register the components
For example, vue router or axios etc....
In addition,  should I add it to the entry clients js file .?

Comment: Back to your question, if your app is medium/large, I highly recommend moving it to higher-level solutions: https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/ssr.html#higher-level-solutions  This will save you a lot of time and headaches. If you prefer to stay at a lower level (Vite with SSR), you can refer to this: https://vite-plugin-ssr.com/ , as mentioned in the docs: https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/ssr.html#vite-ssr